# Converting String binary to integer

Tags: java

How can I do this without using multiplication, division or mod?

I come with the solution but it needs multiplication.

```
public StringBToInt(String b) {
    int value = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z < b.length(); z++) {
        value = value * 2 + (int)b.charAt(i) - 48;
    }
}
```

EDIT: SORRY! Only 3 java API are allowed. length(), charAt(), and equals()

Comment: This homework problem clearly requires addition. Can you use `arrays` or `lists`? Is the input `string` a fixed length?

Comment: Yes, it does allow addition and subtract. No you cannot use array or lists. only Integer and String with charAt(), length(), and equals.

Comment: What about input length? Is it fixed input length, is there variability within a range, or is it potentially infinitely long?

Comment: it is a fixed length . E.g ("1111" ==> 15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without multiplication, use bitwise shift operator:

```
public StringBToInt(String b) {
    int value = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z < b.length(); z++) {
        if(b.charAt(z) == '1'){
            shift = b.length()-z-1;
            value += (1 << shift);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(b.charAt(z).equals('1'){` is missing a closing parenthesis and doesn't work - the primitive type `char` doesn't have an `equals` method!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Integer.valueOf(String, int)` method:

```
Integer.valueOf('10101',2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Integer.parseInt(..)` like this:

```
  int value = Integer.parseInt(b, 2);
```

Ofcourse `b` is a binary String.

Comment: `b.toCharArray()[i]` is the wasteful version of `b.charAt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `Integer.parseInt` to do this.

```
String binary = "101010"
int value = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
```

The '2' in `Integer.parseInt` means to parse the `String` in base 2.